# Android requestLocationUpdates fail

Tags: android, gps, location

I start a service and try to use the requestLocationUpdates which fails the application since there is a NULLpointerException.

Comment: Why have you removed the code and if anyone one post you like most, make it accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't initialize the `locationManager` its just declared.

Answer (score 0):

> Reason for NullPointerException

You did not initialize the locationManger.

Initialize in this way.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location myCurrentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(getBestProvider());
```